# Is there a way to view array elements alongside their index value within the development environment?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm working with pretty large arrays to store constants and it's quite hard to find the correct value to edit since I'd have to count through them.

Is there a an option in visual studio or something to display the arrays in such a way? (e.g. hovering over the element shows it's index in the array)

here's what i'm working with:

```
public static IDictionary<string, Object[]> elementStatus = new Dictionary<string, Object[]>()
        {

         {"Fire", (new Object[spellinfoLength] 
         {"Burn",null,null,null, null, null, null, null,null,null,null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0.5,null,"Fire", null} 
                  )
         },
         {"Lightning", (new Object[spellinfoLength] 
            { "Shock", null, null,  null,  null, null,  null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0.5,
            null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null } 
                        ) 
         }, 

   //etc... (25 more parallel arrays)

       }
```

Any suggestions would help.

Comment: If you replace array with `new Dictionary<int, Object> { {0, "Burn"}, {1, null}}`, you will be still access correct values by"index": `elementStatus["Fire"][0]`

Comment: that wouldn't be a significant thing but if I decided to add an element somewhere in the middle i'd have to renumber all the elements after the one I added, but that would be decent enough if there are no better solutions.

Comment: If you can come up with the names for every item, you can create an enum. Where Dictionary will use enum as key. Adding new enum value in the middle will update automatically other enum values.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an actual class to represent that data rather than just an array of objects. Think about how you're going to use this array - you'll have to be *casting* things all over the place. And as much as that's a funny pun given that we're talking about spells, *casting* in C# is typically a code smell. One of the best things about C# is the strong typing; but by using `object` for everything, you're throwing that away.

The fact that you have `spellinfoLength` tells me that your intention is to have the same number in each array that represents a spell. So you can achieve that by initializing the default values to null once, rather than setting them up via the constructor on each one.

As a side bonus, you now know that you are working with a Spell rather than just a named array of objects.

```
public class Spell
{
    public Spell(string name, string typeOfDamage, double damage)
    {
        Name=name;
        TypeOfDamage=typeOfDamage; // consider using an enum?
        Damage=damage;
        // etc Add more properties here. I cant tell what type the other things in the array are
        // since they are all null.
        // some of these properties may be writable during their lifetime, so for those ones, add a 'set;' as well
    }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string TypeOfDamage { get; }
    public double Damage { get; }
}
```

Now when you use the constructor to create a Spell, each time you press comma inside the bracketed part, intellisense will tell you what the parameter is.

P.S. you can make a dictionary of them based on `Name` like this...

```
public static IDictionary<string, Spell> elementStatus = new[]
    {
     new Spell("Fire", "Burn", 0.5),
     new Spell("Lightning", "Shock", 0.5),
     //etc... (25 more)
   }.ToDictionary(x=>x.Name,y=>y);
```